# 14.04 VLC libde265 unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, vlc

I can't seem to install vlc-plugin-libde265, it's looking for libde265(>=1.02). Any ideas what to do about this?

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265  
Reading package lists... Done       
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some 
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
  vlc-plugin-libde265 : 
        Depends: libde265 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed  
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

VLC Version:

```
$ vlc --version  
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1~trusty2)  
VLC version 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (2.2.1~trusty2)  
Compiled by buildd on lcy01-34.buildd (Feb 17 2016 20:00:02)  
Compiler: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)  
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License;  
see the file named COPYING for details.  
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

apt-cache policy vlc-plugin-libde265 libde265

```
libde265:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.2-1ppa1~utopic1
  Version table:
     1.0.2-1ppa1~utopic1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.2-1ppa1~trusty1.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.2-1ppa1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
vlc-plugin-libde265:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.7-1ppa1~utopic1
  Version table:
     0.1.7-1ppa1~utopic1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
     0.1.7-1ppa1~trusty1.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     0.1.7-1ppa1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Works fine here, that is a ppa version of vlc, (mine) & the ppa provides both the plugin (vlc-libde265 (0.1.7-1ppa1~trusty1.1)) & the lib, (libde265 (1.0.2-1ppa1~trusty1.1)) .  Just tested and both installed fine.  Don't find askubuntu good for troubleshooting like this, on ubuntu forums would gladly help you. Otherwise maybe try some apt-cache policy on both packages, ect.  & good luck

Comment: What ppa did you use? I'll try asking in ubuntu forums as well. Thanks!

Comment: The same where you got vlc, trusty-media. (I created & maintain it.)  So ck. post 3 in uf thread & we can fix this in short order. (though starting to get late here...

Comment: What is our output of `apt-cache policy vlc-plugin-libde265 libde265`? Please edit your question to add it and then notify me with a comment "@ByteCommander". Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander I've edited my question adding the results of apt-cahce

Comment: @ByteCommander, I've already got the solution from Ubuntu Forums. You were on the right path too. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

So I got my answer in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332052. Asked the same question.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```